# Icon is specified both as .xml file and as a bitmap

Tags: android, xml, file-structure, mipmaps, launcher-icon

I recently set my Min SDK version to 26. I ran the code inspector to check for warnings and it asked me to move files in the mipmap-anydpi-v26 to a folder called just mipmap-anydpi, which I did.

However, when I run the code inspector again it says:

> Icon is specified both as .xml file and as a bitmap

and

> The following images appear both as density independent '.xml' files and as bitmap files: src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi/ic_launcher.xml, src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

Now, I'm confused. Do I delete the density independent .XML file or the bitmap (png) files stored in mipmap-hdpi etc. Or do I move the XML files somewhere else or what?

Answer (score 1):

Depends, but I would usually remove the bitmap unless you have performance issues and thousands of images to load. The vector drawables are less to maintain and can be scaled to any size, so they are technically "better", but they take a little bit more time to load.